# Parsing Html with python using lxml

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I have this html page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Some Text
        <a href="aLink">
            Other Text
        </a>
        <a href="aLink2.html">
            Another Text
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am interested in capturing the 3 texts in the file. By doing this, i get in output the texts from the two links:

```
     from lxml import html
     from lxml import etree
     import requests 

     page = requests.get('myUrl')
     tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
     aLink = tree.xpath('//a')
     for link in aLink:
         print link.text #it works
```

But I am not able to obtain the text from the body section, since the following code doesn't work:

```
     body = tree.xpath('//body')
     print body.text
```

What am I supposed to do? Thanks for the answers

Comment: You should reconsider using lxml for parsing html (which is not necessarily xml). I would suggest that you use BeautifulSoup instead.

Comment: Try `tree = html.fromstring(page.text).getroot()`

Comment: @Paco if lxml is installed, then BeautifulSoup will use `lxml.html`'s parser anyway, so it's a bit of a moot point

Comment: @JonClements I get this error: "AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'getroot'"

Comment: @user2567853 yeah ignore me - brain burp. Given a document of `<html><body><p>testing</p><p>something else</p></body></html>` then `tree.xpath('//body/*/text()')` should just work (as an example - but not quite sure exactly what you're after

Comment: Thanks for your help, in this way I get a list of the two texts of the links, but not the first one.